# HTML Tables add / remove rows and change names and make sortable

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

I'm trying to work on a simple script to make a table have the ability to do the following:

1. Add / Remove Rows
2. Enable sorting on the rows
3. Add an additional _numeric number on the end of each field each time a row is added.
4. When the sorting is completed add into a hidden field the sort order of the rows so that i can handle it via a CF template on the server for creating records.

I've tried searching for a plugin to do this, but no luck thus far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="order">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="table-data">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>Options</td>
    <td>Add</td>
    <td>Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone" id="listItem_123">
      <td class="handle">+</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="who" name="who" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="location" name="location" ></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="date_picker" name="start" class="datepicker"></td>
      <td><select name="dave">
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Option1</option>
          <option value="2">Option2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
      <td><input type="button" name="remove" value="Remove" class="tr_clone_remove"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var max_rows = 5;
    counter = $('.tr_clone').length;
    if( parseInt(counter) < max_rows)
        {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find(':text').val('');
        $tr.after($clone);
        }   
});
$("input.tr_clone_remove").live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
$( "#table-data tbody" ).sortable({
            handle : '.handle',
            items : 'tr',
            update : function(){
                var order = $("#table-data").sortable();

            }
    });  
});
</script> 
<style>
#table-data{width:800px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
td.handle{cursor:move}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I've gotten the add / remove function happening with the help of some other posts created on Stack Overflow, but if any assistance can be provided it would be greatly appreciated, or if anyone knows of a plugin that automatically handles this that would be even better.

Comment: You should definitely create a jsFiddle... it will make it easier for everyone to work on.

Comment: thanks for this tip, just waiting for jsfiddle to allow registrations as its having issues at the moment =)

Comment: There are some pretty good plugins for that. Most of these plugins are already well tested and cross browser compatible, so I'd recommend using one, if you are looking for a quick and nice solution. An example I found: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/fQKDw/1/) for you to start with